# docker run puts me into a node repl

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

When I go to run `docker run -p 8080:3000 --name cabinfeverInstance -t something/cabinfever` I get put into a Node.js REPL, when I expect to see "Listening on port: 3000". Going to localhost:8000 results in a "didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". I have found no other instances of this occurring (maybe I am not searching Google for the correct words/tricky phrases).  I did find [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/197) which seems somewhat related. Their solution was to "make the containerized app expect requests from the windows host machine IP (not container IP)", but I am not sure how to implement that. Also, their solution could also not be my solution.

What I have tried:

1. Clean/purging the data.
2. Running `docker run -p 8080:3000/tcp -p 8080:3000/udp --name cabinfeverInstance -t something/cabinfever`
3. Not specifying the specific port (8080).
4. Specifying 0.0.0.0.
5. Several additional ideas.

None have worked and I still get the wonderful Node REPL.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate them.

Here are the relevant files:

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var port = 3000;

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());
    res.send(new Date().toLocaleString());
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at http://localhost: ${port}`);
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "docnode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "barebones node on docker",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "index.js"
  },
  "author": "my.email.address@gmail.com",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.5"
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  node:
    build: .
    command: node index.js
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:slim

LABEL author="my.email.address@gmail.com"

WORKDIR /app

# copy code, install npm dependencies
COPY index.js /app/index.js
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the command to run in the Dockerfile, not the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```sh
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

When you `docker run` an image, the only options it considers are those on the `docker run` command line.  `docker run` doesn't know about `docker-compose.yml`, so if you specify things like `command:` there it won't be honored.  Since the `CMD` isn't in the Dockerfile and it isn't on the `docker run` command line (after the image name), you fall back to the base image's `CMD`, which in the case of `node` is to run the REPL.

With this change you don't need to override `command:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file and you can delete that line.  Running

```sh
docker-compose up -d
```

will start the container(s) in the `docker-compose.yml` file with the options specified there (note, the `ports:` mapping and the `docker run -p` ports are slightly different).